# Marking reference parts in a picture

Tags: html

Code with form to upload an image and upload to mysql:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<form class="form6" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<ul class="flex-outer">
 <li>
     <label for="Data">Data</label>
         <input type="date" class="form-control" id="DataRegisto" name="DataRegisto" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
   </li>
   <li>
        <label for="Utente">Utente</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="Utente" name="Utente">
      <option value="teste">teste</option>
         <option value="teste1">teste1</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="Utente">Utente</label>
   <input type='file' name='files'>
   </li>
    <li1>
        <label for="Observacao">Análise Clínica</label>
        <textarea rows="6" id="Observacao" name="Observacao" placeholder="Digite a sua análise"></textarea>
      </li1>
      <div style="float: right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn6" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="inserir_registo6()">Gravar</button>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </form> 
  </div>
```

The form works fine and also the insert into mysql database.
Prior to inserting into the database, choosing and loading the image would open it in a div and be able to reference the most important parts of the image.

As for example surrounding a zone of the image as shown below:

[image]

and only then insert the image into mysql with these changes.

Can you help?

Comment: What issue are you having? Can you rephrase your question to make it clearer?

Comment: Sounds like you want to edit your image before uploading. That's a lot to ask of volunteers helping to answer questions in their spare time. Perhaps you could focus your question on one aspect you've tried and are having a problem with, show what research you've done and the attempts you've made, then ask that question? See [ask] for more information.